# Want to join to arrays but they dont do it

Tags: c, arrays

Hi Im trying to join to arrays of ints in a new array with undefined size (depending on the first two arrays. But when I run the code it stays in an endless loop, it seems. What am I doing wrong? Ps. The arrays are supposed to end when encountering a -1 Ds.

```
int
main (void) {
   void join(int arr1[], int arr2[]);
   int vectorA[11] = {8, 17, 29, 32, 33, 33, 77, 81, 90, 94, -1};
   int vectorB[11] = {8, 17, 29, 44, 33, 33, 77, 81, 90, 94, -1};

   join(vectorA, vectorB);
return 0;
}

void join(int arr1[], int arr2[])
{
   int count=0, counter=0;
   int i=0, j=0;
   while(arr1[i]>-1)
      count++;
   while(arr2[j]>-1)
      count++;
   int tot[count];
   for(i=0, j=0; ((arr1[i]>-1) || (arr2[j]>-1)); )
   {
       if(arr2[j]<0) {
       tot[counter++]=arr1[i++];
   }
   else if(arr1[i]<0) {
       tot[counter++]=arr2[j++];
   }
   else {
       tot[counter++]=arr2[j++];
       tot[counter++]=arr1[i++];
   }
}

printf("the doubled array is : \n");
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
   printf("%d, ", tot[i]);
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> while(arr1[i]>-1)
>       count++;
> ```

This will never end, since `i` doesn't change. Maybe you meant `arr[i++]` ?